# Figuring out if my problem is about a difference-in-differences with a continuous treatment

Tags: econometrics, causality, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect, generalized-did

I am interested to find the causal effects of a state level policy on some outcome of interest. The policy affects some states each year but not other states. The states that are affected can vary across years.

I am trying to figure out if this is a case of continuous or multi-valued treatment studied in recent DiD literature, for example [here](https://psantanna.com/files/Callaway_Goodman-Bacon_SantAnna_2021.pdf). In my case, I think there is no 'intensity' or 'dose' of the treatment but I am not sure if I should think. Instead, each year, the treatment occurs and is binary.

Can I think of this as a continuous treatment? Also, since another issue is that some units get treated multiple times in the sample period, is it possible to tease-out causality using DiD in such a setting?

Comment: Do you have different levels of treatment? For example, something like a group of states with a low dose and others with a high dose?

Comment: Yes, I think there are different levels of treatment. Some units get higher values of treatment than other units. The main issue is that some units get treated multiple times in the sample period. Is it possible to tease-out causality using DiD in such a setting?

Comment: Can treatment have lasting effects or not? If I get a tetanus shot, it will still have an impact next year but may wear off eventually. Or is it more like a rainy year and crop yields, with no carryover?

Comment: Good question, this is something I want to answer in my research. I don't have much prior except that treatment effects will likely not go beyond one year.

Comment: This is a very complex scenario, with heterogeneity in 1) treatment “amount”; 2) treatment timing; 3) control group, also varying over time. My first concern is whether your data actually allow for such a fine-grained investigation. I would also add that if the treatment effect is not persistent your concern is not just the treatment “amount”, but also the “dosing pattern”. Therefore, I agree with the comments above that it is of vital importance to clearly understand what is at work in your setting, since this may allow you to simplify the model (you can always run some robustness checks).